# WTForms HiddenField() contains no data after POST

Tags: python-3.x, flask-wtforms, hidden-field

I'm very new to Flask and WTForms, but what I'm trying to do is provide a user with a button to allow them to automatically upload a GIF to giphy.com. The GIF is located on the server and rendered to their browser on generate.html. Below the GIF is a Submit button that I intend to have launch an app.route to handle the upload process (opening a new tab which will eventually display a link to the uploaded GIF once that process completes).

Problem: The app.route for the uploading the gif (clicking the submit button) has no data assigned to its HiddenField (gifLocation), despite thinking I assigned it when generate.html was loaded.

My FileLocationForm code:

```
# class for sending along a file path used for uploading a gif
class FileLocationForm(FlaskForm):
    gifLocation = HiddenField()
    submit = SubmitField('Upload to GIPHY')
```

When the GIF is first created on my server, I run the following commands (in the app.route for generate.html):

```
form = FileLocationForm(gifLocation=gif_outfileloc)
return render_template('generate.html', gif_outfileloc=gif_outfileloc[7:], form=form)
```

At this point, gif_outfileloc exists and 100% points to a valid GIF on my server. The 2nd parameter's formating is because I'm displaying a file in the "static" folder, and need to remove "static" from the path, since it's added by flask in the img tag. That part is working.

The code for generate.html:

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="gif_display center-align">
    <img class="img-fluid mx-auto my-auto d-block" width="480" height="360" src={{ url_for("static", filename = gif_outfileloc) }}>   
</div>
<form id='uploadGifForm' action = {{ url_for('generateGIFpage') }} target = '_blank' method='POST'>
    {{ form.gifLocation() }}
    {{ form.submit() }}
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

We get a submit button on the page and clicking it does open a new tab, but it takes us home, instead of uploading to giphy.

Code for generateGIFpage:

```
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def generateGIFpage():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('gifLocation'):
            gifLocation = request.form.get('gifLocation')
            giphyobj = Giphy(API_KEY)
            # response (below) is the URL for our giphy upload
            response = giphyobj.upload([], gifLocation, username="QuoteGIFr")
            return render_template('upload.html', response = response)
    return redirect(url_for('homepage'))
```

Any help is appreciated. I've tried some variations on this, but I haven't had any success yet. If you need anymore code to make sense of what I'm doing, or need more information on what I'm trying to do, please ask.